# unable to populate a crossfilter dimension

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I'm running the following script with node.js and watching the output at localhost:3100.

It outputs the "livingThings" crossfilter with all of the data in it, but when I comment out that res.end line and use the next one to see what's in the "typeDimension" dimension, I just get empty brackets.

Why doesn't my crossfilter dimension have any data in it?

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var cf = require('./crossfilter.js');

var livingThings = cf([
  { name: "Rusty",  type: "human", legs: 2 },
  { name: "Alex",   type: "human", legs: 2 },
  { name: "Lassie", type: "dog",   legs: 4 },
]);

var typeDimension = livingThings.dimension(function(d) { return d.legs; });

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var requrl = (url.parse(req.url, true));
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(livingThings.all()));
        //res.end(JSON.stringify(typeDimension.filterAll()));
     }

).listen(3100, function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will never see anything from second res.end, because res.end is closing of request, and you already closed it. Try to use res.send is you want to pass something, and res.end when you want to end request and send response. And, don't pass any data via res.end, it is a bad habit.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I'm using the second res.end, I'm commenting out the first, so the request shouldn't be closed.